# keeping text in place while DIV's width expands

Tags: html, css

I have a DIV which its width is expanding on hover, and more text is displayed. The problem is that while the div is expanding evenly to both sides (using changing margins) the text is moving to the right like it is keeping its former position inside the div. This happens in chrome and IE but not in Firefox for some reason. I want it to stay at the center if possible. Can be seen at: http://wiki.doalogue.co.il/ while hovering the on the Doalogue wiki headline

**the relevant HTML:**

```
<div id="mf-banner-intro">
    <h2>
<span class="mw-headline" id="DoAlogue_Wiki">
            <big><i>headline:DoAlogue Wiki</i></big>
</span>   
    </h2>
    <h3>
            <span class="mw-headline">Second headline</span>
    </h3>
    <p>The apearing text</p>
    <h4>
            <span class="mw-headline">▼</span>
    </h4>
</div>
```

**The relevant CSS**

```
#mf-banner-intro {
background: rgba(20,20,20,0.85);
margin: 40px 30% 25px 30%;
padding: 20px;
position: relative;
width: 40%;
font-size: 150%;
text-align: center;
opacity: 0.9;
-webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
-o-transition: all 500ms ease;
transition: all 500ms ease;
}
#mf-banner-intro h2 {
font-size: 150%;
text-align: center;
line-height: 100%;
color: #FFF;
border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
margin-bottom: -0.2em;}

#mf-banner-intro p {
color: #FFF;
opacity: 0;
font-size: larger;
padding: 1em 3em;
margin-bottom: -1em;
display: none;
-webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
-o-transition: all 500ms ease;
transition: all 500ms ease;}

#mf-banner-intro:hover {
width: 50%;
margin: 40px 25% 25px 25%;
background-color: rgba(59,164,204,0.88);
-webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
-o-transition: all 500ms ease;
transition: all 500ms ease;}

#mf-banner-intro:hover p {
opacity: 1;
overflow: visible;
display: block;
-webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
-o-transition: all 500ms ease;
transition: all 500ms ease;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: script works fine for me in chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/mC2AN/

Comment: Works fine in chrome v 32 on Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks. It works well also for me in the jsfiddle, so maybe it is something in the site preferences that I'm not aware to?